# Convert std::bitset to decimal std::string

Tags: c++, string, bitset

I have a class for operations on numbers of N-bit lenght in which I use *std::bitset* for storing a number. I have to write a method for converting *std::bitset* to decimal *string*, so that the results of operations can be displayed to user. The problem is I cannot use fundamental types because my number might have hundrets of digits.

Do you have an idea for any algorithm that can do it?

Comment: Looks like there's a `to_string` function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string

Comment: Yes, but it converts to a binary string and what I want is a decimal representation

Comment: Just double-checking: are you sure you need a decimal number? What's wrong with hexadecimal? If you're going to show something to the user, I'm guessing it won't matter to them whether it's decimal or hex--it won't mean anything to them either way. Hex would be way, way easier.

Comment: I'm writing this program as laboratory project and it must have simple interace in wchich user enters two decimal numbers and which operation to perform and gets the result. So unfortunately it must be decimal.

Comment: And I know that displaying such long numbers don't tell anything to the user but I only do this to meet the requirements

Comment: Might want to look for some big number libraries.

Comment: You say it's a lab assignment? Converting a binary value *hundreds* of digits long into decimal? That's going to be hard even for professionals. Were you taught anything that could be applied to this problem? Is your prof in the habit of giving you super-hard problems without discussing any of the basics with you?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think that for now I'll just convert and display in hex because i have no time to solve this problem.